# How to read one line at a time from a data file and to perform calculations in it before moving to the next line in C Programming?

Tags: c, loops, data-files

I'm a beginner at C programming and I would appreciate some help in order to understand the problem.

Alright so, I have a data file (input.dat) with data like this: (first line) 0 2 3 4 5; (second line) 1 2 3 5 4, (third line and so on...). I'm required to read the data **one line at a time** until the end of file and print it. This is what I have done so far:

```
int main(void)
{
float coeffs[5];
FILE *input;  /* File pointer to the input file */
fopen_s(&input, "input.dat", "r"); /* Location of the input file */
int count = 0;
/* Loops to read data set*/
while (fscanf_s(input, "%f %f %f %f %f ", &coeffs[0], &coeffs[1], &coeffs[2], &coeffs[3], &coeffs[4]) != EOF)
{
    printf("a=%.4f; b=%.4f; c=%.4f; d=%.4f; e=%.4f\n", coeffs[0], coeffs[1], coeffs[2], coeffs[3], coeffs[4]);
    count++;
}
return 0;
}
```

This is showing all of the lines in the data file at once. But this is not what I want. **I need to read one line at a time and perform some calculations and conditions for that one line first before I move to the next line.** So how can I do that?

Next problem is, for the first line, I need to implement a loop from **-10 to +10 with increment of 2 (to get 11 results in total)**. For example the program will read the first line, display it on the screen, then for the first value -10, the program will calculate and again display something . Then it will do the same for -8, then for -6 and so on until +10. After the 11 results are displayed, **the program will then and ONLY then, move to the second line and so on.** Hence for each line in the data file, the program will have 11 results. How can I use the loop function with increment of 2 to achieve these 11 results?

I would appreciate if anyone can provide me a simple layout of the structure of the codes which I've to write. NOTE: The formats are a bit different than other compilers as I must use Microsoft Visual Studio to do it.

Comment: What are the down-votes for? I'm just trying to understand the base of the problem. :/

Comment: If your input is formatted with exactly five whitespace-separated numbers per line, then your code will indeed read one line at a time.  It indeed does perform some calculations (`printf()` and `count++`) for each such line.  What's not working about that?

Comment: I imagine the downvotes are related in part to that, and in part to the fact that you show no effort to solve the second part of your question.

Comment: The output of my code displays all the lines of the data file at ONCE when I run. Is it possible that it only displays the first line, then if I press ENTER, it displays the second line and so on?

Comment: I actually have no idea how to solve the second part of the question being a beginner. That's why I'm here.

Comment: The program's output for each line immediately follows that for the previous line because you don't output anything else in between.  You don't notice a delay because computers can do this sort of thing very swiftly.  If you want to do additional work per input line (prompt, read a response from the user, ...) then code for that would go into the loop.

Comment: As for you being a beginner, this is not a tutorial site, nor really even a help site.  That we provide help is a happy side effect of our mission to create a database of on-topic questions and answers that will be useful to others.  The downvoters do not think your question meets our criteria, which you can and should read about here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: Ahhh I get it now. So it indeed does read one line at a time.

Comment: @John...Oh I see. I will try to keep that in mind next time I'm asking a question. Thanks for your time to comment. Really appreciated!

Comment: It seems you really are missing some fundamentals of programming - repeating a numeric pattern and running a code block for each number in there is day 1 or day 2 of learning how to code.
That is likely the reason for the downvotes - we can't write a coding basic tutorial on every question here.

Try reading this to start fiiling up your knowledge gap: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_loops.htm

Comment: I will take a look at that. Thank you very much! @jsbueno

Answer (score 1):

Add your calculations to your while loop. You are reading one line at a time anyway.

If you want to loop from -10 to 10 with increments of 2, use a for loop.

```
for(count = -10; count <= 10; count = count + 2)
    {
        // Calculations
    }
```

Comment: The for loop will go inside the while loop, am I right?